# ELB request redirection or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

If a client calls a load balancer of an application, are 2 connections made:

- one from client to load balancer
- other from load balancer to node

Or are requests redirected to a single node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELB Classic and Application Load Balancer do not autonomously generate redirects.  There are two connections used for HTTP mode, one toward the browser and one toward the instance, but there is not a 1:1 correlation -- back-side connections are sometimes reused across multiple clients, and subsequent requests from a single client with a single keep-alive connection may arrive at the back-end via a different connection.  (ELB Classic also supports a Layer 4 mode, in which case the connections are 1:1 correlated).

If a redirect is observed in an ELB/ALB environment, it was generated by a back-end server.

Comment: Thanks for response Micheal. I am a bit confused here. Just to clear this out  if client is trying to make an http request to a node via elb url, requests gets propagated via elb to a node i.e client knows about elb and elb knows about the node to which it is connected, No direct connection between client and actual server node is made ?

Comment: @SahilGupta you are right that no direct connection exists between the client and the back-end instance.  When you say "redirect" in the context of HTTP, this implies an HTTP redirect -- e.g. `301 Moved Permanently` or `302 Found` or one of the other 3XX redirect responses.  An ELB doesn't redirect -- it *forwards* the HTTP request to an instance over a second connection.

Comment: Thanks micheal .. really appreciate the help.